# A fair die is rolled 15 times. What is the probability that at least 8 ones are rolled given no twos?

Tags: probability, statistics

Is the probability of at least $8$ ones given by ${15 \choose 8} (1/6)^{15}$ ?

I know that's probably way off. I don't know how to approach the "given no twos" part either.

Comment: You can consider it to be a five sided die.

Comment: Is the first part I wrote okay in that case? And the (1/6)^15 would be replaced by (1/5)^15?

Comment: That being said, $\binom{15}{8}\times \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{15}$ is going to be the probability that out of 15 rolls of a fair die, *exactly* $8$ of them are $1$'s and the remaining $7$ of them are $6$'s.  You made three big mistakes here.  The first is that you neglected to account for the "at least" part, you should be summing several such terms together, one for "exactly 8", another for "exactly 9", another for "exactly 10" and so on...  The next big mistake was that you used $\frac{1}{6}$ as the probability for each of the fifteen terms., but you just wanted "not a 1" for the others

Comment: No, that overcounts the cases with more than eight ones.  You need to specifically count the cases with eight ones, which means the rest of the dice have to be some other number.  Then compute the probability of nine ones, and ten, and so on.

Comment: "Not a one" occurs with probability $\frac{5}{6}$ usually.  The third big mistake was again that you didn't account for the conditional aspect of this.  Given that no twos occurred, you have the conditional probability of rolling a $1$ as being $\frac{1}{5}$ and the conditional probability of *not* rolling a $1$ as being $\frac{4}{5}$ as opposed to the $\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{5}{6}$ like usual.

Comment: What would the probability be then? I'm just a bit lost with this in terms of notation and understanding

Comment: Relevant reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{i=8}^{15} {15 \choose i} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^i \left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^{15-i} = \frac{129386893}{30517578125} = 0.00423975.$$

Given that you have no $2$s, you can consider the die to have just five equally likely sides (as noted by @RossMillikan).  We sum the binomial expansion for $8 \to 15$ successful events (appearance of a $1$), each of which has probability of $1/5$ and the probability of failure $4/5$ on any single roll.

Here's the relevant binomial distribution (for the appearances of $1$s):

[image]

Notice that, as expected, the most likely number of appearances of $1$s is $3$ (because $1/5 \cdot 15$).

You sum this from $8 \to 15$ (inclusive).

Comment: Can you try to explain how one could arrive to this solution logically? I feel like it's just difficult for me to conceptualise in practise, despite the fact that the answer makes sense to me

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would get it:

By Bayes, P(at least 8 ones | 0  twos)  = P(at least 8 ones and 0 twos ) / P(0 twos)

P(least 8 ones and 0 twos ) = $\sum\limits_{k=8}^{15}$P( k ones and 0 twos)

P(k ones and 0 twos) = $\binom{15}{k} \text{P(1 one in 1 try)}^k \text{P(0 two and 0 ones in 1 try)}^{15-k}$

P(1 one in 1 try) = $\frac{1}{6}$

P(0 two in one try and 0 ones in one try) = $\frac{4}{6}$

And finally,  P(0 twos) = $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{15} $

With that, you can compute the probability.